# Shell script file unable to clone showing ssh error

Tags: bash, git, shell, scripting

I have written a for loop shell script which will clone the repo and perform gitleaks on that repo.

```
user="git clone git@gitlab.com:company/repo/"  
declare -a arr=("company-sre.git")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo $user"$i"
    /Users/mkaly001/go/bin/gitleaks --repo=$user"$i" --report=comapanyrepo_leaks.json
done
```

Above code is kept in one file `gitsecrets.sh`. After executing `./gitsecrets.sh` file the following error is shown on the terminal.

```
 git clone git@gitlab.com:company/repo/company-sre.git
 unable to generate ssh key: open /Users/mkaly001/.ssh/id_rsa: no such file or directory
```

When I do `git clone` it was working fine form terminal.

Comment: `--repo=$user"$i"` is letting "$user` be string-split, so the result is `gitleaks --repo=git clone git@gitlab.com:company/repo/company-sre.git --repo=companyrepo_leaks.json` -- note that there aren't any quotes keeping the `git` and `close` commands in the same string as the `git@gitlab.com` repo definition.

Comment: initially, it is not cloning. echo $user"$i"

Comment: ...beyond that, the message about not finding a ssh private key is pretty obvious on its face, no? How is your account supposed to be authenticating? If you're using an SSH agent, you need to be sure the environment variables are plumbed through.

Comment: You can't trust `echo` to give you an honest view of what's happening -- `echo ls "hello world"` and `echo ls hello world` are very different commands, but they have 100% identical output. Run `bash -x ./gitsecrets.sh` to put trace-level logs that show how content is formed into arguments on stderr -- in a form where you can copy-and-paste those trace logs as commands to run/edit/test them individually.

Comment: ...anyhow, more important than figuring out how to run `git clone` on its own and have it work is figuring out how to run `gitleaks` on its own and have it work -- once you have *that* (and the `bash -x` trace logs showing how gitleaks is *actually* being invoked), we can start piecing things together.

Comment: (Silly question, btw -- do you have a `~/.ssh` directory at all? Does creating one change the error message you get?)